# Is it possible to use Ionic with Angular2 and NO Cordova, for a PWA

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

so I'd like to use Ionic for a progressive web app but obviously since its a pwa (just web + offline) there is no need for the whole Cordova stack.
Mostly would like to use it for its CSS and nice UI / styles.

Is this supported? Didn't find anything in their docs.

Regards,

Sean

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just delete the reference to `cordova.js` from the `index.html`, and maybe call Angular 2's `enableProdMode()` yourself. You can then pretty much use the build you get when you're running your app in browser preview.

Comment: I am wondering is this a supported feature or kind of a "hack"? tx Sean

Comment: It's neither. Ionic 2 is essentially a collection of css and js, and some native plugins if you want them. Here, you're opting to just use the css parts. It's not a feature per se, but neither is it doing something you're not supposed to.

Comment: Some more discussion on the subject: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/building-ionic2-app-for-browser/42208/14

Comment: Ah excuse me, didn't read the title. I'll delete the comment. Thought he wanted to use Ionic 2 as a CSS framework

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in ionic cli for that `--no-cordova`

You can read about how to use it in below link
http://robferguson.org/2017/04/29/build-a-desktop-application-with-ionic-3-and-angular-4/